# Cannot delete entity with ComplexType property (Entity Framework 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

This has been driving me nuts for a week now.

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class SuggestionVote
{
   public virtual int ID { get; set; }
   public virtual Suggestion Suggestion { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
   public virtual VoteTypeWrapper VoteType { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime DateVoted { get; set; }

   // Equality overrides omitted
}
```

`VoteTypeWrapper` is actually an enum wrapper based on an article [on how to fake enums in Entity Framework 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-23-how-to-fake-enums-in-ef-4) and looks like this:

```
public class VoteTypeWrapper
{
        private VoteType _type;
        
        public int Value
        {
            get { return (int)_type; }
            set { _type = (VoteType)value; }
        }

        public VoteType EnumValue
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

        public static implicit operator VoteTypeWrapper(VoteType voteType)
        {
            return new VoteTypeWrapper { EnumValue = voteType };
        }

        public static implicit operator VoteType(VoteTypeWrapper voteTypeWrapper)
        {
            return voteTypeWrapper == null ? VoteType.NotVoted : voteTypeWrapper.EnumValue;
        }
}
```

with the `VoteType` enumeration being:

```
public enum VoteType
{
   Up,
   Down,
   NotVoted
}
```

I've also defined a `ComplexType` in the model designer:

```
<ComplexType Name="VoteTypeWrapper" >
   <Property Type="Int32" Name="Value" Nullable="false" />
</ComplexType>
```

The voting system I'm implementing works somewhat like StackOverflow's voting system: The user can vote up or down; voting a second time undoes the previous vote, and voting in the opposite direction (i.e., down when previously voted up) undoes the vote as well.

Now for the problem. Voting once works like a charm and all the values are correctly saved to the database. Undoing a vote, however, refuses to work. To undo a vote I basically mark the vote to undo for deletion and then call `SaveChanges` on the context.
As soon as I do that an `InvalidOperationException` occurs giving me the following message:

```
The entity of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SuggestionVote_4A3949F5B95E9A51567509467230FD7CEA0FB7761C3AC9C8C2BBC62BCAA033AF' 
references the same complex object of type 'Web.Model.VoteTypeWrapper' more than once. 
Complex objects cannot be referenced multiple times by the same entity.
```

I just don't get it. Down anyone know what I could be doing wrong? I've been Googleing for day but to no avail

Comment: Are you sure this was the reason? ComplexType?

Comment: A bit weird as I guess I'm having the same problem right now. The entity also has a complex type property for an enum. Don't want to jump to the conclusion quickly

Comment: @Mohammed: Well in my case `VoteTypeWrapper`, which is the complex type, was the property mentioned in the error message (see above) so I think it is safe for me to assume the complex type was the reason. Also, as soon as I removed it everything worked. If it looks like a duck, sounds like a duck... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've finally decided to work around it but simply mapping an `int` property instead of a `ComplexType`. I have also added a (non-mapped) helper property to avoid having to cast constantly from `int` to `VoteType`.

I would still love to get an answer for my problem so if you can help it I would appreciate it. I'll give it a couple of days before I mark my own answer as correct.

**EDIT:** Since I've gotten no answer whatsoever to this, m marking my own answer as good.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same problem. I have a class that contains a complex type that contains another complex type. Let's call them Class1, Complex1 and ChildComplex. My scenario is the following (I don't know if it matches yours, but the error message is exactly the same).

I retrieve from the context an instance of Class1 and perform a change in a property of Complex1. I then call SaveChanges to the context and get the same exception :

```
The entity of type '<Class1>' references the same complex object of type '<Complex2>' more than once. 
Complex objects cannot be referenced multiple times by the same entity.
```

I have not found a decent workaround other than cloning the Complex1 instance, replacing the cloned version in the Class1 instance and then making the change. That way EF does not complain that it's the same complex object.

This is a really strange behaviour. If I have time (around 2038) I'll try to isolate it and report it to MS, smells like a bug...

Answer (score 0):

I've just been searching for this same issue, but I've just realized I was misreading the error.  Its not complaining that your entity has two properties of the same type, its complaining that your storing the 'exact' same object of that type in both properties.

In my case I was doing a lookup on an table to get my complex type, and I now realize that if the lookup returned the same value it would be the same object.

I fixed this by creating a new object of my complex type and setting its values to the same as the lookup.